# Proof of Barbier's Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, geometric-probability

In the probabilistic proof of Barbier's Theorem, I'm not sure why the expected number of line crossings of a continuous curve is the limit of the expected number of line crossings of piecewise linear functions approximating it.  The proof of the theorem can be found on the Wikipedia page for "Buffon's Noodle", but the step I'm interested in is omitted.

Comment: Do you mean 'Buffon's Needle'? Don't know whether he also came up with a noodle.

Comment: No I mean "Noodle".  The noodle is a generalization to continuous curves.

Answer (score 1):

the formula is true for a needle, then for 2 needles thanks to the additivity of the expectation, then it's true for 2 needles glued together, then for a piecewise linear curve. For closed smooth curve, you can approximate with a piecewise linear curve inside and outside, thus the expectations are all equal at the limit.